# Graph showing value even if the value is specified to 0 using flot

Tags: javascript, flot, bar-chart

This is my fiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/44/

It is successfully plotting the graph. The problem which i am facing is that it is showing the   value of two(one of the legends in the graph) below the red line even if i specify it to zero. Why is this happeneing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the bars option, set the lineWidth to 0:

```
   bars : {
        fill : 1,
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.7,
        lineWidth: 0
    }
```

Comment: Awesome Mark... You are my savior :D